# Mail sending don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

Using device for  users in my app. In development mode all works correctly, but when tried it in production, then I have problems. My `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'radiant-journey-52383.herokuapp.com'}
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      user_name:      ENV['SENDMAIL_USERNAME'],
      password:       ENV['SENDMAIL_PASSWORD'],
      domain:         ENV['PROD_MAIL_HOST'],
      address:       'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:          '587',
      authentication: :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

What I have done wrong?

Comment: are there any errors visible?

Comment: @Luke No only type on the page 
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

If you are the application owner check the logs for more information. You can test it radiant-journey-52383.herokuapp.com

Comment: Please check the application llog

Comment: Make sure you have assigned proper values to the environment variables on heroku - `ENV['SENDMAIL_USERNAME']`

Comment: Are you trying to send mail through GMAIL ?

Comment: @Deepak Mahakale yes it can be a solution to set ENV in heroku host, but how can I do that?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @Vishal yes, with gmail

Comment: Did you set `ENV['SENDMAIL_USERNAME']` ? If not than please go to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars and set config vars

Comment: @Vishal yes at the moment mails is sending, but here depends a new problem) when I tried to log in it say me again "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

Comment: I would recommend that you use `ENV.fetch('SENDMAIL_USERNAME')`. `ENV.fetch` raises an error if the var is not set and makes it much easier to spot configuration errors as Rails will fail on startup. Use it for every configuration setting that is required.

Comment: Gmail also requires you to do an extra step to allow the heroko app in your email account. Mailgun or SendGrid are actually simpler to setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use domain: 'gmail.com'
use port number with url
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: 'radiant-journey-52383.herokuapp.com', port: 3000}
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      user_name:      ENV['SENDMAIL_USERNAME'],
      password:       ENV['SENDMAIL_PASSWORD'],
      domain:         'gmail.com',
      address:       'smtp.gmail.com',
      port:          '587',
      authentication: :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```